# c# comparing arrays

Tags: c#, linq, list

good afternoon everybody

the question is kinda simple but I've been having problems the whole afternoon

i have 2 lists:

- list of ints (ids)
- list of objects (that contains ids)

and i want to compare them but i want to obtain the id that doesn't have a pair (if it exists)

i was wondering if there's a c# or linq method to identify the values that are different in two arrays

example

if i have

```
List<int> ids = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

and

```
List<objectX> x = (contains id,code, and description)
```

and i was trying something like

```
foreach (int id in ids)
        {
            foreach (objectX item in x)
            {
                if (item.id == id)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    idDiferentes.Add(id);
            }
        }
```

but like you can imagine it doesn't work

for example

```
ids= {1,2,3,4}
objectx[id] ={1,3,2}
```

the ids are different when i compare them so i get a bigger list that the one i need

i also tried with an linq outer join but i don't understand how it works pretty well

Comment: `if (item.id != id) idDiferentes.Add(id)`, and please don't use "u" instead of "you" and "i" instead of "I".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var idsWithoutObjects = ids.Except(x.Select(item => item.id));
```

Answer (score 7):

What you are after is the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension method. It gives you the set difference between two sequences.

So you can do something like this (pseudo c#-code):

```
var idDifferences = x.Select(item => item.id).Except(ids);
```

Answer (score 3):

Linq Set Operations:

```
int[] A = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,     } ;
int[] B = {     2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , } ;

int[] A_NotIn_B = A.Except( B ).ToArray() ;
int[] B_NotIn_A = B.Except( A ).ToArray() ;
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to LINQ (although LINQ is probably the right answer here), if all your ids are unique you may be able to use the `Contains()` method, for example:

```
foreach(objectX item in x)
{
    if(!ids.Contains(item.id))
    {
        idDiferentes.Add(item.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use a flag, e.g.:

```
bool b = False;

foreach (int id in ids)
        {
            foreach (objectX item in x)
            {
                if (item.id == id)
                {
                    b = True;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

if (!b)
{
    idDiferentes.Add(id);
}
```

Comment: this would not compile. Among other issues, you have the `if (!b)` outside of the outer `foreach`, and `id` is no longer in scope.

Comment: Excelent Guys Thank you very much for your help, thanks to you i could solve my problem